# how is the code for picker view selected item?

Tags: iphone, ios4

how is the code for picker view if i selected the any item from the Pickerview it as to show the related alert message.
exe: In picker view consists "RED",YELLOW","BLOCK","GREEN" from the picker view if i selected  the  RED Alert message "THIS IS RED".
so help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the picker delegate method.

```
       -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
       {
              mString.text=    [arrayNo objectAtIndex:row]; //mString is a NSString defined and the arrayNo is the NSArray that contain all your color data.

       }
```

Now you have the selected value in your mString object then use that object in the alert message.

You can refer [this](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/8315-uipickerview-selected-item.html) discussion

Answer (score 1):

Set a delegate and use `- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component`
 in`- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component`

Read the Apple Doc about that:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIPickerViewDelegate